# Dialogflow send custom payload json from webhook

Tags: json, dialogflow-es

From Dialogflow console, i can set a custom payload like this

[image]

How can i send the exact same response from a webhook custom integration.

I tried sending it from Flask as JSON but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using a webhook you have to send back a complete WebhookResponse. Unfortunately, the documentation for the webhook protocol seems to have gone missing when they migrated the documentation from dialogflow.com to cloud.google.com/dialogflow. However, it is still available in the [Dialogflow Discovery document](https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v2). If you look for the `GoogleCloudDialogflowV2WebhookResponse` there you'll see that you would have to send back something like this:

```
{
    "payload": {
        "facebook": {
            "attachment": {
                # ... etc.
            }
        },
        "slack": {}  # ... etc.
    }
}
```

The format for version `v2beta1` of the Dialogflow API is the same.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Too bad this is not clearly documented.

Answer (score 5):

```
{
    "fulfillmentText": "Your text response",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
        {
            // this item is optional
            "text": {
                "text": [
                    "Your text response"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "payload": {
                // Your custom fields payload
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for! I couldn't find appropriate position for payload & wasted bunch of hours. :/ Thanks!